# How do I draw the contents of arrays stored in a list?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, xna, ienumerable

I have a file containing scores in the following format:

```
000001,1
000002,2
000012,1
232124,1
```

I build an array containing the score as the first element and the difficulty as the second element. I then add the array to the list like this:

```
// load highscores
public void LoadScores()
{
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader("highScores.txt");

    // loop through each line in the file
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // seperate the score from the difficulty
        lineData = line.Split(',');

        // add each line to the list
        list.Add(lineData);
    }
    OrderScores();

}
```

Next I order the list using an `IEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> scoresDesNormal, scoresDesHard;

// order the list of highscores
protected void OrderScores()
{
    // order the list by descending order with normal difficulty at the top
    scoresDesNormal = list.OrderByDescending(ld => lineData[0]).Where(ld => lineData[1].Contains("1"));
    // order the list by descending order with hard difficulty at the top
    scoresDesHard = list.OrderByDescending(ld => lineData[0]).Where(ld => lineData[1].Contains("2")).Take(3);
}
```

Now I want to print the two `IEnumerable` lists to the screen using `spriteBatch.DrawString()`. How do I correctly iterate through the list elements and the arrays in side of them? I want to print out both elements of each array stored in the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your question.

If you **do** know how to draw 1 string, and you want to draw 2 strings combined with a separator between them ",", simply do this:

```
...
string firstString = ...
string secondString = ...

string toBeDrawn = firstString + "," + secondString;
DrawThisFellah ( toBeDrawn );

...
```

So, you have a `string[]` ? No problem:

```
...
string[] currentElement = ...

string firstString = currentElement[0];
string secondString = currentElement[1];
// etc
...
```

Secondly, you don't need to add the leading zeros just for the alphabetical `OrderByDescending` to work. You **could** parse (and thus validate) the strings and store them in elements of type `int[]` instead of `string[]`.

**THIRD**, and this might interest you !

It is dangerous to use LINQ without knowing you're using it.
Are you aware that your `IEnumerable<string[]>` are actually *queries*, right ?

One could say that your `IEnumerable<string[]>` objects are actually "CODE AS DATA".
They contain **not the result** for your `OrderByDescending` but rather the logic itself.

That means that if you have say, 3 `string[]` elements in your `lineData`:

```
{ "1", "122" }, { "3", "42" }, { "5", "162" }
```

and you call `OrderScores`, then you will notice the results when enumerating `scoresDesNormal` (for instance). The following code:

```
foreach (var element in scoresDesNormal)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", element[0], element[1]);
```

would print out to the console:

```
1, 122
5, 162
```

(because the 2nd element has no '1' characters on the second subelement)

**but** if you go on and modify the `lineData` collection either by inserting new elements or removing elements (should it be a `List<string[]>`) or simply by modifying the values of existing elements (should it be a primitive array), then you will observe new results when enumerating `scoresDesNormal` **without** calling `OrderScores` !

So for instance the following code's comments are true (given you have a `List<string[]> lineData`):

```
List<string[]> lineData = new List<string[]>(new[] {
    new[] { "1", "122" }, // contains 1
    new[] { "3", "42" },  // does not contain 1
    new[] { "5", "162" }  // contains 1
});

OrderScores();

foreach (var element in scoresDesNormal)
    Console.WriteLine(element[1]);
// the previous foreach prints out
//    162
//    122

lineData[1][1] = "421"; // make the "42" in the list become "421"

foreach (var element in scoresDesNormal)
    Console.WriteLine(element[1]);
// the previous foreach prints out - even though we haven't called OrderScores again
//    162
//    421
//    122
```

Answer (score 0):

If i were you, i would do it like this,

If the user clicks or presses a button to view scores, open a method, like this one.

```
public void DisplayScores()
{
Rectangle[] PositionOfText = new Rectangle[scoresDesNormal];
for (int i = 0; i< scoresDesNormal.Count; i++)
{
PositionOfText = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, Width, Height);
}
//do the same for the other difficulties, this sets the position of the texts.
```

import a fontbatch that you would like to use. 
and in your draw method have something like this,

```
for (int i = 0; i< scoresDesNormal.Count; i++)
spritebatch.drawString(MyFontBatch, scoresDesNormal[i], PositionOfText, Color.//your preffered color.
```

Now i can understand that their may be errors in that, but i'm not a fluent c# programmer, But thats more or less what you can do

Comment: I'm not convinced that is correct because `scoresDesNormal[i]` is an object. I need to loop through the array as well.